# Send a Video Sharing Message via Youtube API V3

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-channels, youtube.net-api

Does anyone know how to send a video sharing message in the new Youtube API V3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the messaging system hasn't been implemented yet in v3. Google are still working on the 3rd version of the YouTube API, so all features aren't included at this point. It still exists in v2 though.

Take a look here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: so now Can I use v2 instead of v3? And where can I download v2 client library? Thank you.